# html editor for vb.net 2005

Tags: vb.net, html-editor

I am trying to let the user preview HTML email before sending it.

Does anybody have or know where I can get a simple HTML editor or control that render HTML withou using the webbrowser control?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the Webbrowser control?

Comment: i have one written in c#, and trying to convert it to vb.net throws many errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several HTML editors for .Net Windows Forms, but most of them internally use the WebBrowser control and put it in edit mode.

For example:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/WFtinyMCE.aspx
Or this one
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/editor_in_windows_forms.aspx

Comment: ok thanks, the code is inc c#, i tried converting to vcb.net, but got many errors?